# mysql bash shell script outputting erro

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, cron

I am trying to create a bash shell script that runs an sql query and later on create a cronjob that runs it at an specific time.

I created my bash script see below

```
mysql -u $host -D $dbname -u $user -p$password -e $mySqlQuery
```

I have wrap -u -D -p -e all in variables.   I have also change it to and executable file.   When i run it.  it gives out an output stating.  Command not found.  can anyone tell the mistake i made?

Below is the bash script

```
host="host"
user="user"
dbname="database"
password="password"
mySqlQuery = "SELECT *
FROM invoice i
  JOIN item it
    ON it.invoice_id = i.id
  JOIN user u
    ON i.user_id = u.id
  JOIN gateway_response gr
    ON gr.invoice_id = i.id

WHERE  i.created_at >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00' and
i.created_at <= '2019-03-17 23:59:59' and i.status=9"

mysql -u $host -D $dbname -u $user -p$password -e $mySqlQuery
```

Below is the error i am receiving when i run it.

```
/home/chris2kus/givingDetectRun.sh: line 8: mySqlQuery: command not found /home/chris2kus/givingDetectRun.sh: line 20: mysql: command not found –
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it using the full path to the mysql command? Ex.: /usr/local/bin/mysql -u $host -D $dbname -u $user -p$password -e $mySqlQuery

Comment: Also, I suggest you to use double quotes around your variable names, i.e., use "$host" instead of just $host

Comment: @RodElias what is the difference wrapping the variables in double quotes?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

There must be no spaces around the `=` and the variable name `mySqlQuery`.

Also, I suggest you wrap your variables around double quotes, i.e., use "$host" instead of just $host.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a file like this and **chmod 755 filename.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash

host="localhost"
dbname="test"
user="root"
password="xxxxxxxxxx"

mySqlQuery="select * 
from col;"

mysql -u $host -D $dbname -u $user -p$password -e "$mySqlQuery"
```

**Sample**

```
$chmod 755 testmysql.sh
$
$ ./testmysql.sh 
+----+------+------+------+
| id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
|  2 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
|  3 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
+----+------+------+------+
$
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, make sure your line 5 looks like 
`mySqlQuery="SELECT..."`

(notice no spaces on either side of the assignment operator)

For seconds, try to re-format your entire MySQL query to fit into a single line.
(perhaps Heidi since it's a query, since that will keep you at least syntax-wise in the clear of errors)

For thirds, once you confirm that the bash runs as intended, add \n to tell the bash that you're continuing the command in the next row

Prototyping before optimization. Get it running before you get it flying.